# When to use site-start.el vs init.el

Tags: init-file

I am using Vincet Goulet's modified version of Emacs that use `site-start.el`.

http://vgoulet.act.ulaval.ca/en/emacs/

I have read the description of its use but I don't understand exactly what conditions may affect choosing `site-start.el` over `init.el`. Can someone clarify a *rule of thumb* on this?

Comment: Type:  `M-x describe-variable RET site-run-file RET` and take a look at the doc-string.  If you wish to see at what location it is called in the startup process, type `M-x find-library RET startup RET` and search for the `site-run-file` references within the library.

Comment: Could you provide a link for the Emacs version you're using?

Comment: Is `site-site.el` a typo?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> [The] init file [...] specifies how to initialize Emacs for you. 
>   [Therefore it is normally located in (a subdir of) your home directory.]
>   [You] may also have a *site startup file* [...] named `site-start.el`. [It is normally located] in a subdirectory named `site-lisp` in the Emacs installation directory, such as `/usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp` [but] you can place [...] `site-start.el` in any of the directories which Emacs searches for Lisp libraries. 
>   [...]
>   We recommend against using `site-start.el` for changes that some users may not like.

(see [The Emacs Initialization File](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html))

In a multi-user environment, as an admin, you put in `site-start.el` the customisations intended for all users, while single users will use their own init file.
Also, if you make a customised Emacs distro, you put specific distro packages, together with `site-start.el`, in the `site-lisp` directory.

Before the personal computing era, having a centralised Emacs server was a necessity due to the mainframe computing model, which required so called *site customisations*. A typical scenario nowadays is that each user has their own Emacs on their own computer, perhaps a laptop. Therefore there is not much need for site customisations, including  `site-start.el`.

Anyway you might use Emacs as a daemon to manage your emails, you org agenda notifications, etc. In this case  `site-start.el` is the proper place to craft your daemon.